# Calculation of the divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

How do the derivatives [the divergence] in the volume give the flux [vectors] out of the boundary?

It doesn't appear to do that; when ever I think of these derivatives, particularly derivatives like constant values, they don't total up to any value which I calculate on the boundary. What is the step I have forgotten?

For example: When ever $F = \langle x, y, 0 \rangle$ inside the rectangle between the axis and the planes where $x=2,y=5,z=2$:

$\dfrac{\partial F_{x}}{\partial x}$ = $1$.

$\dfrac{\partial F_{y}}{\partial y}$ = $1$.

$\dfrac{\partial F_{z}}{\partial z}$ = $0$.

$\displaystyle \iiint_{V} div(F)dV = \int_{z=0}^{z=2} \int_{y=0}^{y=5} \int_{x=0}^{x=2} 2 \; dxdydz$

$\displaystyle \iiint_{V} div(F)dV = \int_{z=0}^{z=2} \int_{y=0}^{y=5} 4 \; dydz$

$\displaystyle \iiint_{V} div(F)dV = \int_{z=0}^{z=2} 20 \; dz$

$\displaystyle \iiint_{V} div(F)dV = 40 = \iint_{S} F \cdot n \; dS$

That is as far as I can get to, will someone write out the surface integral [and thereby teach how to dot with the normal vector] because that would be so helpful - the divergence's scalar and the values along the boundary do not seem to be equal when I thought about them..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is far too vague a question for us to be able to answer. Can you please include a specific problem *and* your work to show what you think is going wrong? By the way, flux is a scalar — it measures how much of the vector field is going across the surface.

Comment: I put my work into the revision, please read and help if you're still available.

Comment: To create the surface integral, there are 6 surfaces that have to be handled, one for each face of the solid.  for example, one face is in the xy-plane.  The flux through that surface is zero, since the normal vector is in the negative $\hat{k}$ direction, and the vector field has a zero component in that way.  You have to do each of the 6 faces separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 6 faces, and the flux has to be calculated separately through each.  I will show a couple:

(1) One face is in the $xy$-plane. The flux through that surface is zero, since the normal vector is in the negative $\hat{k}$ direction, and the vector field has a zero component in that way.

(2) Take the face in the plane $x=2$.  For this face, the outward normal is in the positive $\hat{i}$ direction.  This yields the integral
$$\int F \cdot d\hat{n}=\int_0^2 \int_0^5 ⟨x,y,0⟩   \cdot <1,0,0>dydz$$
Since $x=2$ in this plane, we simply get
$$\int_0^2 \int_0^5 2dydz=20$$
Can you do the others?

Comment: At the plane y = 5, $\displaystyle \int_{z=0}^{z=2} \int_{x = 0}^{ x = 2} \langle x,5,0 \rangle \cdot \langle 0,1,0 \rangle \; dxdz = 20$.

At the other planes the divergence has to equal to zero.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  So the total flux is equal to $20+20+0+0+0+0=40$

Comment: I couldn't figure out how $\dfrac{\partial F_{x}}{\partial x}$ at the point $(4,1)$ was not 4 in that dimension. It is the vector (x,y) but at the point 4,1 so the partial is still actually 1? I am confused !

Comment: For that face $x$ is constant.

Comment: Why is $dn$ used in the equation instead? I think it should be $F \cdot n$ right????

Comment: Not sure which equation you're referring to, but yes, that is correct.